# Is there a way to change the "DropDown"-Font of a ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, fonts, combobox

I have a `ComboBox` containing `Unicode` symbols, the font is set to a Unicode-Supporting font and it displays them just fine. But the DropDown section seems to use a standard font which cannot display these `Unicode symbols`. Is there a way to change this inside the properties or do I have to create a customized `ComboBox` control?

[image: DropDown-Section of a ComboBox]

**EDIT:**

My Code:

```
public class MainWindow : Form {
    ...

    public BindingList<Sound> Sounds { get; set; } = new BindingList<Sound>();
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.comboBox.DataSource = this.Sounds;
    }

    ...
}

public class Sound {
    public char Symbol { get; private set; }
    public Sound(char symbol) {
        this.Symbol = symbol;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() {
        return this.Symbol.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        if(obj is Sound) {
            return this.Symbol == ((Sound)obj).Symbol;
        }
        return base.Equals(obj);
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return this.Symbol.ToString();
    }

    public void Play() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show what symbols are those (some of the `\uxxxx` codes). Where do they come from and how are they inserted? (This, usually, doesn't happen)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Are you using a standard WinForms ComboBox? If so, what Unicode symbols are you using? Also, what is the ComboBox's current font?

Comment: I'm using a standard WinForms `ComboBox` with the Font set to `Segoe UI Symbol` which can display these symbols when using a label or anything else just fine. These are some of the codes, (IPA symbols): \u0260, \u0263, \u027E
Also I'm using a `BindingList<CustomType>` where the `ToString()` method in the `CustomType` was overwritten with the symbol. It is used as a Data Source.

Comment: Well, what matters is the **code** that produces these results.

Comment: Okay edited the question to dispaly my current code.